# Radio buttons are not working in jquery formbuilder

Tags: jquery, cakephp-3.0, formbuilder

I am creating dynamic forms on my website using [jquery formbuilder](https://formbuilder.online/).
These forms are saved and provided for the users to fill the details and saved in the database. For some reason, the radio buttons on the form are not getting selected in the user's view but they are working when I create the form.
There are no console errors.

Comment: Can you check the name of the radio button? Is it also dynamic for different sets of radio buttons? If they have the same name only one of them might be getting selected

Answer (score 0):

It can be user end problem like cookies or cache. Cookies stores information such as user preferences, while cache will keep resource files such as audio, video or flash files.

Comment: Issue is not from browser end.I have checked it.

Comment: OK, So it may be a bug. What is it?